# Using Namespace nested resources with MongoMapper EmbeddedDocument with form_for

Tags: namespaces, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongomapper, form-for, nested-resources

I'm submitting a form that is sending in a child resource's `id` value for both the child resource and it's parent resource's `id`. I don't know how to get the form submission to stop duplicating the child id as the parent resource's id.

Technology Stack:

- Rails 3.2.8
- MongoMapper
- Simple Form (although the same issues occur with the stock form_for that it wraps)

Relevant excerpt from `routes.rb`:

```
namespace :mock do 
  resources :patients do
    resources :allergies
  end
end
```

My models are defined in `Mock::Patient` and `Mock::Patient::Allergy`.

In my Allergy resource's view partial _form.html.erb, I have the following opening form helper usage (I use Simple Form, but the same results occur with the stock form_for helper):

```
<%= simple_form_for [@mock_patient, @mock_allergy], :url => mock_patient_allergy_path(@mock_allergy),  do |f| %>
```

While this renders, it is submitting to this route:

/mock/patients/:patient_id/allergies/:id

So my allergies_controller.rb file does receive an update action (in the case of an edit operation).

However, when I look at the params, params[:patient_id] is the same as params[:id]. Both are actually the id value of the specific nested allergy resource being edited. By the parent resource (Patient in this case) has its context lost.

So, I set out to include a hidden field in the form:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag('patient_id', @mock_patient.id) if @mock_patient %>
```

When I view the page source before submitting the form, sure enough, I can see the *correct* `patient_id` value.

There seems to be some built in form handling logic that is replacing the parent resource's id with that of the child resource.

My model files, using Mongo Mapper are:

```
class Mock::Patient
  include MongoMapper::Document
  # other Patient model keys here
  many :allergies, :class => Mock::Patient::Allergy 
end

class Mock::Patient::Allergy
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument
  # other Allergy model keys here
  belongs_to :patient, :class => Mock::Patient
end
```

To recap, I'm able to finagle the form tag to submit to the correct route, but the params hash received by the controlled is jacked up - losing the parent resource context.

Other variations of my form tag that I've tried, to no avail:

```
<%= simple_form_for @mock_allergy, :url => mock_patient_allergy_path(@mock_allergy),  do |f| %>
```

and

```
<%= simple_form_for @mock_allergy, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

In the above both cases, the basic route template generated is fine, and it reaches my allergies_controller, but when I go to inspect `params[:patient_id]`, I get an incorrect value. It is actually a duplicate of `params[:id]`.

#### Concrete Example

My form tag line:

```
<%= simple_form_for @mock_allergy, :url => mock_patient_allergy_path(@mock_patient, @mock_allergy) do |f| %>
```

This generates a page that when I view source, reports:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" 
action="/mock/patients/5092c815fdb5424df800000d/allergies/5092c815fdb5424df800001c" 
class="simple_form form-horizontal" 
id="edit_mock_patient_allergy_5092c815fdb5424df800001c" method="post" 
novalidate="novalidate">
```

But when it hits my controller, who looks to find a Mock::Patient based on the on params[:patient_id], it doesn't get the '5092c815fdb5424df800000d' value I would expect. On my browser, the error page indicates the parameters received were:

```
{ "patient_id"=>"5092c815fdb5424df800001c",
          "id"=>"5092c815fdb5424df800001c" }
```

These two IDs are identical, and therein lies the problem.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

#### Solved:

In my update method, on success the redirect from scaffolding was:

```
redirect_to @mock_allergy
```

instead of:

```
redirect_to mock_patient_allergy_path(@mock_patient, @mock_allergy)
```

So, I was getting punted to a correctly formed route, but with a bogus patient_id.

My other mistake, was that in modeling Allergy, I should have used an `embedded_in :patient` instead of the `belongs_to :patient` line.

### Derived Question:

Why is it, that `@mock_allergy`, and instance of `Mock::Patient::Allergy`, knowing it is a nested resource, couldn't generate a correct path that included the right `patient_id`?